# A command for toggling between text colours

Tags: syntax-highlighting

How might one write a command that toggles between the settings `hi Normal ctermfg=8` and `hi Normal ctermfg=12` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could add this code to your `$MYVIMRC` file :

```
nnoremap <leader>t :call ToggleForegroundColor()<CR>

function! ToggleForegroundColor()

let fgcolor=synIDattr(hlID('Normal'), 'fg#')

if fgcolor == 8
    hi Normal ctermfg=12
else
    hi Normal ctermfg=8
endif

endfunction
```

After saving and sourcing it, you should be able to toggle between the two values by pressing `<leader>t`.
If your `<leader>` is the comma key, it would be `,t`.

You can define your `<leader>` key in your `$MYVIMRC` file with something like this :

```
let mapleader = ","
```

To explain the code :

```
nnoremap <leader>t :call ToggleForegroundColor()<CR>
```

This line maps `<leader>t` to a function called `ToggleForegroundColor`.
The function is defined just afterwards and is responsible for toggling the value of the `ctermfg` argument.

```
let fgcolor=synIDattr(hlID('Normal'), 'fg#')
```

This line assigns to the variable `fgcolor` the value of the foreground color number of the Normal highlight group (`ctermfg` if you're inside a terminal, `guifg` if you're inside gvim).

For more information about the built-in functions used here, you can have a look inside the help : `:h synIDattr` and `:h hlID`.

The rest of the code is a simple `if else endif` structure which tests the value of `fgcolor` to change the value of `ctermfg` accordingly.